# LIKE MySQL search not functioning with CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a problem regarding SQL query. If single word SQL query can detect the string, but if I add multiple words inside the string, it won't show any results.

```
SELECT * FROM rules WHERE keyword LIKE CONCAT('%','$message','%')
```

Input 1 (show results)

```
$message = "ASK"
```

Input 2 (show no results)

```
$message = "I WANT TO ASK"
```

Comment: Your `CONCAT` expression treats `$message` as a string literal. Try removing single quotes around `'$message'` inside `CONCAT`.

Comment: it won't show any results either using input 1 and 2

Comment: Can you share your sample data, or better yet - an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) ?

Comment: you can use this link, http://128.199.153.235/api/create_group.php?mobilePhone=0176347239&message=ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want those rows where the value of the keyword column is part of the message. That's the typical use case for key words.

If that's right then you've get this result with the help of the function [INSTR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_instr):

```
SELECT * FROM rules WHERE INSTR('$message', keyword) > 0;
```

While

```
SELECT * FROM rules WHERE '$message' LIKE  CONCAT('%', keyword, '%');
```

would work most times too, it's got the restriction that the keyword musn't contain the wildcard characters for the LIKE operator: `%` and `_`. INSTR doesn't have this restriction.